# Swift 3.0 Remove duplicates in Array of Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, dictionary, set, swift3

I am working removing the duplicate Dictionaries in an array of Dictionaries in swift 3.0

The below is the

```
let Dict1 : [String : String] = ["messageTo":"Madhu"]
let Dict2 : [String : String] = ["messageTo":"Kiran"]
let Dict3 : [String : String] = ["messageTo":"Raju"]

var arrOfDict = [[String:String]]()
arrOfDict.append(Dict1)
arrOfDict.append(Dict2)
arrOfDict.append(Dict1)
arrOfDict.append(Dict3)
arrOfDict.append(Dict2
print(arrOfDict)

//prints [["messageTo": "Madhu"], ["messageTo": "Kiran"], ["messageTo": "Madhu"], ["messageTo": "Raju"], ["messageTo": "Kiran"]]
```

As you can see there are 2 duplicate dictionaries in the arrOfDict.

can any one help me out in filtering the duplicates using **Set** or any other approach

Comment: hello did you find the solution? i am facing the same issue

Comment: yes jigar dfri solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries does not conform to `Hashable` (or `Equatable`), so using `Set` is not an available approach in this case. For dictionaries where `Key` and `Value` types are `Equatable`, however, we have access to the `==` operator for readily performing a uniqueness filtering of the array of dictionaries:

> ```
> public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(
>             lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
> ```

E.g. as follows (`O(n^2)`)

```
arrOfDict = arrOfDict.enumerated()
    .filter { (idx, dict) in !arrOfDict[0..<idx].contains(where: {$0 == dict}) }
    .map { $1 }

print(arrOfDict)
// [["messageTo": "Madhu"], ["messageTo": "Kiran"], ["messageTo": "Raju"]]

// or ...
arrOfDict = arrOfDict.enumerated()
    .flatMap { (idx, dict) in !arrOfDict[0..<idx].contains(where: {$0 == dict}) ? dict : nil }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func removeDuplicates(_ arrayOfDicts: [[String: String]]) -> [[String: String]] {
var removeDuplicates = [[String: String]]()
var arrOfDict = [String]()
for dict in arrayOfDicts {
    if let name = dict["messageTo"], ! arrOfDict.contains(name) {
        removeDuplicates.append(dict)
        arrOfDict.append(name)
    }
}
return removeDuplicates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is duplicated, because you add `Dict1` and `Dict2` 2 times. May i ask why?

`Set` would not work for you, because `Dictionary` type does not conform to the `Hashable` protocol, only its `key` property.

You can do a validation on the dictionary, if there is already a value like that, do not append it to `arrOfDict`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this :

```
var set = NSSet(array: arrOfDict)
```

Comment: I don't think we need `NS` in Swift 3.0 anymore