# Remove duplicate dictionary from array of dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

How to remove duplicate dictionary from array of dictionary.

**Response:**

```
[  
   {  
      "voter_id":1
   },
   {  
      "passport":1
   },
   {  
      "pan_card":1
   },
   {  
      "aadhaar_card":1
   },
   {  
      "voter_id":1
   },
   {  
      "aadhaar_card":1
   }
]
```

We need a output like below

```
[  
       {  
          "passport":1
       },
       {  
          "pan_card":1
       },
       {  
          "aadhaar_card":1
       },
       {  
          "voter_id":1
       }

    ]
```

I am trying this link but does not helping me..

[Swift 3.0 Remove duplicates in Array of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381075/swift-3-0-remove-duplicates-in-array-of-dictionaries?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to remove duplicated keys

```
func removeDuplicate(list: [[String:Any]]) -> [[String:Any]] {
    var alreadyKnowKeys: [String] = []
    var newArray: [[String:Any]] = []

    list.forEach { (item) in
        if let key = item.keys.first {
            if !alreadyKnowKeys.contains(key) {
                newArray.append(item)
                alreadyKnowKeys.append(key)
            }
        }

    }

    return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just convert the array of `[String: Int]` to `Set`

```
var foo = [
[
    "voter_id":1
],
[
    "passport":1
],
[
    "pan_card": 1
],
[
    "aadhaar_card":1
],
[
    "voter_id":1
],
[
        "aadhaar_card":1
    ]
]
Set(foo) // Usage
```

Comment: order will change right if use Set

Comment: Yes, Set is not sorted in anyway sometimes they remain the same order sometimes they don't however if it was response to decode order wont be matter in any matter, i thought the question without regarding the order, however hope this would help either now or in the future, i also recommend reading about the data structures in swift, would save you plenty of headache

Comment: no problem, good luck